# How to passe parametres to ajax url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I try to get data from database using ajax and I think I have a problem in the ajax url

my json result in this url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/manage/JournalVente.php?method=jason&popup=1
```

the result is

```
[{"IDCUSTOMER":"255","NBORDER":"10","DATE_SAVE":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","DATE_SEND":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","COMPANY":"haboussa","PAYMENT_TYPE":"CHQ","TOTAL_TTC":"0.00"}]
```

and my code is

```
function Load() {
    $('#update_panel').html("<img src='../static/loading.gif' />");

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/manage/JournalVente.php?method=jason&popup=1',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (d) {
            // alert(d.length);
            if (d.length > 0) {
                var $data = $('<table></table').addClass('table table-responsive table-striped');
                var header = "<thead><tr><th width='5px' class='no_sort'></th><th width='5px' class='no_sort'></th><th width='5px' class='no_sort'></th><th>R&eacute;f&eacute;rence</th><th>Date saisie</th><th>Date &eacute;ch&eacute;ance</th><th>Client</th><th>Type de paiement</th><th>Montant</th></tr></thead>";
                $data.append(header);       

                $.each(d, function (i, row) {
                    //alert(row.FIRSTNAME);
                    var $row = $('<tr/>');
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html("<a href='invoice.php?idcustomer=" + row.IDCUSTOMER + "'&idorder=" + row.IDORDER + "'&print=1' target='_blank' ><img src='../static/css/actions/pdf.png' border='0' /></a>"));
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html("<a href='?method=update_details&idcustomer=" + row.IDCUSTOMER + "'&idorder=" + row.IDORDER + "'><img src='../static/css/actions/edit.png' border='0' /></a>"));
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html("<a  href='?method=delete&idorder=" + row.IDORDER + "'&popup=1' class='popup-delete'><img src='../static/css/actions/delete.png' border='0' /></a>"));
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(row.NBORDER));
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(row.DATE_SAVE));
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(row.DATE_SEND));
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(row.COMPANY));
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(row.PAYMENT_TYPE));
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(row.TOTAL_TTC));
                    $data.append($row);
                });
                alert($data)
                $('#update_panel').html($data);
            }
            else {
                var $noData = $('<div/>').html('No Data Found!');
                $('#update_panel').html($noData);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error! Please try again.')
        }
    });
}
```

it always give me the alert Error! Please try again.

Comment: Your "jason" results is actually json:)

Comment: is it cross domain data access? if yes consider using `dataType: 'jsonp',`

Comment: I see your are using a table to display your data. Why don't you use jTable? It's a nice and easy CRUD framework.

Comment: I'm using datatable it mutch easy from jTable

Comment: @jai no it not ........

Comment: @Newlife try removing this `http://127.0.0.1:8888` from the url. a leading `/` does the same. if you provide host and port this sometimes creates issues.

Comment: If you're trying to access the 127.0.0.1:8888 from a browser URL that isn't 127.0.0.1:8888, the browser is likely blocking you from making the cross-site call. There's a good blog post here about how to configure your server to support cross domain traffic and make cross domain requests using jQuery: http://zinoui.com/blog/cross-domain-ajax-request. Also note that AJAX requests will also fail if you're running your application from a file:// URL (you need to be running the script from a web server with http:// or https://).

Comment: mention xhr in error function and n theput it in alert .then let me know what is the exact error???

Comment: If it's not cross domain, what's the status code on the response? Anything 4xx or 5xx would trigger the error callback.

Comment: Why don't simply use `data: { /* some_parameters */ }` ?